# Better way to merge two JSONs

Tags: android, json, kotlin, merge

I have a list and I want to merge them to one `JSON`.
What is the best method?

I have already tried this, but the data struct is not I want.

```
val list = mutableListOf<FakerData>()

        val jsonA = FakerData()
        val jsonB = FakerData()

        list.add(jsonA)
        list.add(jsonB)
```

**JSON A**

```
{
  "R": {
    "RC": {
      "odd": "0.97",
      "ratio": "2.5 / 3"
    }
  }
}
```

**JSON B**

```
{
  "R": {
    "RH": {
      "odd": "0.82",
      "ratio": "2.5 / 3"
    }
  }
}
```

I want merge then and the data struct  like this.

```
{
  "R": [
    {
      "RC": {
        "odd": "0.9",
        "ratio": "0 / 0.5"
      }
    },
    {
      "RH": {
        "odd": "0.94",
        "ratio": "0 / 0.5"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: you need to separate the "R" and then create a json array for it and the rest as objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
     JSONObject jsonA=new JSONObject("{\"R\": {\n" +
                "    \"RC\": {\n" +
                "      \"odd\": \"0.97\",\n" +
                "      \"ratio\": \"2.5 / 3\"\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "}");
        JSONObject jsonB=new JSONObject("{\"R\": {\n" +
                "    \"RC\": {\n" +
                "      \"odd\": \"0.97\",\n" +
                "      \"ratio\": \"2.5 / 3\"\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "}");

        JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray();
        jsonArray.put(jsonA);
        jsonArray.put(jsonB);
```

Output:

```
[{"R":{"RC":{"odd":"0.97","ratio":"2.5 \/ 3"}}},{"R":{"RC":{"odd":"0.97","ratio":"2.5 \/ 3"}}}]
```

Comment: The data struct is not I want.